# TextField selection initialization problem

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I have a `textField`, I initialize its value to zero when the application starts, and the first time I click on the field, the cursor moves to position 0 instead of 1

```kotlin
val state = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("0", TextRange(1))) }
    
TextField(
    value = state.value,
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Decimal
    ),
    onValueChange = { state.value = it }
)
```

The problem goes away if you leave `onValueChange` empty, since I understand that when `textField` is initialized, it sends the value where the cursor is `TextRange.Zero`. Isn't this a bad effect?

The solution that I have found so far is to initialize the state with a delay, but this is a crutch and not a solution.

What are the solutions?

Comment: why because when you run app for the first time it have string size of 0 so cursor move to 0

Comment: Do you need selection also?

Comment: @ChiragThummar but I set text with selections, why set 0 when I set 1.

Comment: @AbhishekTiwari I try different variants, but cursor always set in 0 position for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this modifier fixes the issue.

```kotlin
modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
```

See [Why does the cursor always appear at the start of my OutlinedTextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75839561/why-does-the-cursor-always-appear-at-the-start-of-my-outlinedtextfield)

```kotlin
var textFieldValue by rememberSaveable(
                        stateSaver = TextFieldValue.Saver
                    ) {
                        mutableStateOf(
                            TextFieldValue(text = "0", selection = TextRange(1))
                        )
                    }

                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize(),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        TextField(
                            modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max),
                            value = textFieldValue,
                            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Decimal
                            ),
                            onValueChange = { newTextFieldValueState ->
                                textFieldValue = newTextFieldValueState
                            }
                        )
                    }
```